# To use the second variant of FeatureDetector on an image set

Tags: opencv, sift, feature-detection

I was able to successfully load a number of images into a vector, `vector<Mat>`. The images once loaded in can be displayed with the `imread` function.

The problem is that I want to apply SIFT on this set of images using the second variant, as mentioned in the documentation:

```
void FeatureDetector::detect(const vector<Mat>& images, vector<vector<KeyPoint>>& keypoints, const vector<Mat>& masks=vector<Mat>() ) const
```

This is producing the following error:

```
error C2664: 'void cv::FeatureDetector::detect(const cv::Mat &,std::vector<_Ty> &,const cv::Mat &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const cv::Mat &'
```

The code I am using:

```
vector<Mat> images;

/* code to add all images to vector not shown as its messy but it was performed with FindFirstFile of windows.h. All images loaded correctly as they can be read by imread*/

initModule_nonfree();

Ptr<FeatureDetector> get_keypoints = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
get_keypoints->detect(images , keypoints);
```

The error is detected at `get_keypoints->detect(images , keypoints);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `detect` signature, `keypoints` should be `vector<vector<KeyPoint>>`, yet you declare it as `vector<KeyPoint>`.

Comment: Thank you. How could I miss that